# Задать классу высоту браузера в стиле

Tags: jquery

Вообщем есть.

```
<div class="height-build">
```

Нужно чтоб в style писалась высота браузера.
Знаю что это делаеться вот этой функцией $(window).height();
Но сделать готовый код не могу.
Прошу помощи.

UPD можно сделать какнить будь вот так?

```
<div class="height-build" style="min-height: Размер высоты окна браузера">
```

Comment: а это не 100%?

Comment: при 100% появляеться полоса прокрутки и стр, можно прокрутить вниз(

Comment: и `overflow: hidden` конечно же не подходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вообще через `jQuery` это делается так:

```
$('.height-build').css('min-height',$(window).height());
```